# Spline interpolation in Fortran

Tags: fortran, interpolation, spline

I'm running a spline interpolation on two small arrays in Fortran, it works but I get numbers that are either a bit off or really off.

Can anybody tell me if I made any mistakes in the logic or the formulas?

```
SUBROUTINE spline(x, y, n, y1, yn, y2)
! =====================================================
! Input x and y=f(x), n (dimension of x,y), (Ordered)
! y1 and yn are the first derivatives of f in the 1st point and the n-th
! Output: array y2(n) containing second derivatives of f(x_i)
! =====================================================
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER:: n, i, j
INTEGER, PARAMETER:: n_max = 500
REAL*8, INTENT(in):: x(n), y(n), y1, yn
REAL*8, INTENT(out):: y2(n)
REAL*8:: p, qn, sig, un, u(n)

IF (y1 > .99e30) THEN    ! natural spline conditions
  y2(1) = 0
  u(1) = 0
ELSE
  y2(1) = -0.5
  u(1) = (3./(x(2)-x(1)))*((y(2)-y(1))/(x(2)-x(1))-y1)
END IF

DO i = 2, n-1                            ! tridiag. decomposition
  sig = (x(i)-(i-1))/(x(i+1)-x(i-1))
  p = sig*y2(i-1)+2.
  y2(i) = (sig-1.)/p
  u(i)=(6.*((y(i+1)-y(i))/(x(i+1)-x(i))-(y(i)-y(i-1))/(x(i)-x(i-1)))/(x(i+1)-x(i-1))-sig*u(i-1))/p
END DO

IF (yn > .99e30) THEN   ! natural spline conditions
  qn = 0
  un = 0
ELSE 
  qn = 0.5
  un=(3./(x(n)-x(n-1)))*(yn-(y(n)-y(n-1))/(x(n)-x(n-1)))
END IF

y2(n)=(un-qn*u(n-1))/(qn*y2(n-1)+1.)

DO j = n-1, 1, -1          !  backwards substitution tri-diagonale
  y2(j) = y2(j)*y2(j+1)+u(j)
END DO
RETURN

END SUBROUTINE spline

SUBROUTINE splint(x_in, y_in, spline_res, n, x_0, y_final)
! =====================================================
! Subroutine that does the actual interpolation
! Input arrays of x_in and y_in=f(x), spline_res is the result of 
! the 'spline' subroutine, x_0 is the corresponding value we are looking for
! i.e. (time_at_max in hubble), y_final is the output result
! =====================================================
IMPLICIT NONE
 INTEGER:: n, k, k_low, k_high
 REAL*8, INTENT(in):: x_in(n), y_in(n), spline_res(n), x_0
 REAL*8, INTENT(out):: y_final
 REAL*8:: a, b, h
 
 k_low = 1
 k_high = n
 
99 IF (k_high - k_low > 1) THEN
   k = (k_high + k_low) / 2
   IF (x_in(k) > x_0) THEN
     k_high = k
   ELSE
     k_low = k
   END IF
GOTO 99
ENDIF

h = x_in(k_high) - x_in(k_low) 
IF (h == 0) STOP "Bad x_in input"
a = (x_in(k_high)-x_0)/h
b = (x_0 - x_in(k_low))/h
y_final = a*y_in(k_low)+b*y_in(k_high)+((a**3-a)*spline_res(k_low)+(b**3-b)*spline_res(k_high))*(h**2)/6

RETURN 
 
END SUBROUTINE splint

SUBROUTINE spline_interp(x, y, n, x0, y_out)
! =====================================================
! Simply merging spline and splint in one subroutine
! input x and y and get y_out at x0
! =====================================================
IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER::n
  REAL*8, INTENT(in):: x(n), y(n), x0
  REAL*8, INTENT(out):: y_out
  REAL*8:: y1, yn, res(n)
  
! natural conditions attempt, change if not working well

y1 = 0.5
yn = 0.5
  
CALL spline(x, y, n, y1, yn, res)

CALL splint(x, y, res, n, x0, y_out)

END SUBROUTINE spline_interp
```

I'm then trying to interpolate the time of maximum brightness of a supernova, having the time of observation and the magnitudes at each moment:

Time (JD):
53682.03732
53683.04882
53684.08633
53687.03535
53689.11806
53690.06398
53694.10385
53695.10682
53698.06705
53699.09681
53702.10265
53706.12631
53716.10135
53721.06836
53726.0874
53730.07961
53738.03101
53746.03825
53755.03675

Mag in b band: 17.117
17.015
16.935
16.838
16.863
16.903
17.167
17.25
17.562
17.664
18.045
18.583
19.37
19.713
19.945
20.141
20.328
20.357
20.547

[image]

As you can see from the light curve, the supernova was at peak brightness at 53687.03535, but the interpolation is giving me 53639.43568130193.

Even worse, I also need to interpolate the brightness 15 days after the peak, which looks like should be around 18.5 mag; but instead I'm getting this random number: -5142981.630692291

What's wrong with my spline?

Thank for your help and sorry for the long post guys
<3

Comment: Please do not use unrelated tags for your question. If you want to write code in Fortran90, then it is not a Python question.

Comment: The best way to find `mistakes in the logic or the formulas" is to break your code into small units, where you know what each unit is supposed to do, and add unit tests to those units.

Comment: I have difficulty reconciling "it works" with "I get numbers that are either a bit off or really off". If you think it works, what tests have you performed to show that, and hence what gaps are left where the seeming errors can come from?

Comment: Can you add the algorithm that finds the maxima. Do you consider the nodes only, or are you solving a quadratic equation to find the zero slope between nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data provided is not indicative of the chart shown

[image: fig1]

So I am going to answer based on synthetic fake data that I made up for this example.

[image: fig2]

with the code

#### Program

The program uses the code from the NR book, and the question above, and put it into a module called `mod_splines` for usability purposes. This way it can be easily extended.

```
program FortranConsoleSpline
use mod_splines
implicit none

! Variables
real(wp), allocatable :: xi(:), yi(:), h, x, y, yp
type(spline) :: sp
integer :: i, n
! compile with /fpconstant
xi = [0.0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0,1.25,1.5,1.75,2.0]
yi = [18.0,18.4921875,18.9375,19.2890625,19.5,19.5234375,19.3125,18.8203125,18.0]

print *, 'Cubic Spline Interpolation Demo'

n = 11
h = (xi(size(xi))-xi(1))/(n-1)
sp = spline(xi, yi)
print *, ""
print '(1x,a6,1x,a18,1x,a18,1x,a18)', "Index", "x", "y", "yp"
do i=0,n-1
    x = xi(1) + i*h
    y = sp%value(x)
    yp = sp%slope(x)
    print '(1x,i6,1x,g18.11,1x,g18.6,1x,g18.6)', i, x, y, yp
end do
print *, ""

x = sp%extrema()
i = sp%indexof(x)
y = sp%value(x)
yp = sp%slope(x)

print *, "Local Extrema"
print '(1x,a6,1x,a18,1x,a18,1x,a18)', "Index", "x", "y", "yp"
print '(1x,i6,1x,g18.11,1x,g18.6,1x,g18.6)', i, x, y, yp


end program FortranConsoleSpline
```

#### Output

The code has been extended by using a bisection method to find the local min/max of the cubic spline. I could have used a direct evaluation by solving the quadratic equation, but this is fast enough.

The result below finds the maximum point at `x=1.1857554913`

```
 Cubic Spline Interpolation Demo

  Index                  x                  y                 yp
      0   0.0000000000            18.0000            2.06799
      1  0.20000000000            18.4009            1.87745
      2  0.40000000000            18.7637            1.73300
      3  0.60000000000            19.0861            1.47687
      4  0.80000000000            19.3398           0.943939
      5   1.0000000000            19.5000           0.209478
      6   1.2000000000            19.5304          -0.461936E-01
      7   1.4000000000            19.4106          -0.938651
      8   1.6000000000            19.1328           -1.85224
      9   1.8000000000            18.6726           -3.07239
     10   2.0000000000            18.0000           -3.50827

 Local Extrema
  Index                  x                  y                 yp
      5   1.1857554913            19.5308           0.738816E-07
```

As you can see the slope at the maximum point is about `1e-7`.

#### mod_splines

Here is the module I created for this demo. The spline coefficients are calculated using the `spline(x,y)` interface (for natural spline) or `spline(x,y,dy_1,dy_n)` for known end slopes.

The spline coefficients are stored together with the input `(x,y)` nodes in a user-defined type called `spline`.

Evaluation of the spline, and its derivatives are done with `value(x)`, `slope(x)` and `slope2(x)` type bound methods.

Additional auxiliary methods are `indexof(x)` to find the integer index where `x(i) <= x < x(i+1)`, and `extrema()` which as mentioned above uses a bisection to find the `x` value where the slope is nearest zero.

```
module mod_splines
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env
implicit none

integer, parameter :: wp = real64
real(wp), parameter :: big = 1e30_wp, tiny=1/big

type :: spline
    real(wp), allocatable :: x(:), y(:), y2(:)
contains
    procedure :: indexof => sp_index_of_x
    procedure :: value => sp_interpolate_value
    procedure :: slope => sp_interpolate_slope
    procedure :: slope2 => sp_interpolate_slope2
    procedure :: extrema => sp_find_local_extrema
end type

interface spline
module procedure :: sp_calculate_from_data
end interface

contains

pure function sp_calculate_from_data(x,y,y1_slope,yn_slope) result(sp)
! =====================================================
! Input x and y=f(x), n (dimension of x,y), (Ordered)
! y1 and yn are the first derivatives of f in the 1st point and the n-th
! Output: array y2(n) containing second derivatives of f(x_i)
! =====================================================

type(spline) :: sp
real(wp), intent(in) :: x(:), y(:)
real(wp) :: y2(size(y))
real(wp), optional, intent(in) :: y1_slope, yn_slope
real(wp):: p, qn, sig, un, u(size(y))
INTEGER:: n, i, j

    n = size(y)
    IF (present(y1_slope)) THEN    ! natural spline conditions
        y2(1) = -0.5
        u(1) = (3./(x(2)-x(1)))*((y(2)-y(1))/(x(2)-x(1))-y1_slope)
    ELSE
        y2(1) = 0
        u(1) = 0
    END IF

    DO i = 2, n-1                            ! tridiag. decomposition
        sig = (x(i)-(i-1))/(x(i+1)-x(i-1))
        p = sig*y2(i-1)+2.
        y2(i) = (sig-1.)/p
        u(i)=(6.*((y(i+1)-y(i))/(x(i+1)-x(i))-(y(i)-y(i-1))/(x(i)-x(i-1)))/(x(i+1)-x(i-1))-sig*u(i-1))/p
    END DO

    IF (present(yn_slope)) THEN   ! natural spline conditions
        qn = 0.5
        un=(3./(x(n)-x(n-1)))*(yn_slope-(y(n)-y(n-1))/(x(n)-x(n-1)))
    ELSE
        qn = 0
        un = 0
    END IF

    y2(n)=(un-qn*u(n-1))/(qn*y2(n-1)+1.)

    DO j = n-1, 1, -1          !  backwards substitution tri-diagonale
        y2(j) = y2(j)*y2(j+1)+u(j)
    END DO
    
    sp%x = x
    sp%y = y
    sp%y2 = y2
    
    RETURN
end function sp_calculate_from_data

elemental function sp_index_of_x(sp,x) result(k_low)
class(spline), intent(in) :: sp
real(wp), intent(in) :: x
integer:: n, k, k_low, k_high
    n = size(sp%y)
    k_low = 1
    k_high = n
    if(x<sp%x(k_low)) then
        return
    elseif (x>sp%x(k_high)) then
        k_low = k_high-1
        return
    end if
    do while(k_high - k_low > 1) 
        k = (k_high + k_low) / 2
        IF (sp%x(k) > x) THEN
            k_high = k
        ELSE
            k_low = k
        END IF
    end do
end function

elemental function sp_interpolate_value(sp,x) result(y)
! =====================================================
! Subroutine that does the actual interpolation
! Input arrays of x_in and y_in=f(x), spline_res is the result of
! the 'spline' subroutine, x is the corresponding value we are looking for
! i.e. (time_at_max in hubble), y is the output result
! =====================================================
class(spline), intent(in) :: sp
real(wp), intent(in) :: x
real(wp) :: y
integer:: n, k 
real(wp):: a, b, c, d, h, t
    n = size(sp%y)
    k= sp%indexof(x)
    h = sp%x(k+1) - sp%x(k)
    IF (h == 0) error STOP "Bad x input"
    t = (x-sp%x(k))/h
    a = 1-t
    b = t
    if( x>=sp%x(k) .and. x<=sp%x(k+1)) then
        ! Cubic inside the interval
        c = (a**3-a)*(h**2)/6
        d = (b**3-b)*(h**2)/6
    else
        ! Linear outside the interval
        c = 0.0_wp
        d = 0.0_wp
    end if
    y = a*sp%y(k)+b*sp%y(k+1)+c*sp%y2(k)+d*sp%y2(k+1)

    RETURN
end function sp_interpolate_value

elemental function sp_interpolate_slope(sp,x) result(yp)
! =====================================================
! Subroutine that does the actual interpolation
! Input arrays of x_in and y_in=f(x), spline_res is the result of
! the 'spline' subroutine, x is the corresponding value we are looking for
! i.e. (time_at_max in hubble), yp is the output result slope
! =====================================================
class(spline), intent(in) :: sp
real(wp), intent(in) :: x
real(wp) :: yp
integer:: n, k 
real(wp):: a, b, c, d, h, t
    n = size(sp%y)
    k= sp%indexof(x)
    
    h = sp%x(k+1) - sp%x(k)
    IF (h == 0) error STOP "Bad x input"
    t = (x-sp%x(k))/h
    a = -1/h
    b = 1/h
    if( x>=sp%x(k) .and. x<=sp%x(k+1)) then
        ! Cubic inside the interval
        c = (1-3*(1-t)**2)*(h/6)
        d = (3*t**2-1)*(h/6)
    else
        ! Linear outside the interval
        c = 0.0_wp
        d = 0.0_wp
    end if
    yp = a*sp%y(k)+b*sp%y(k+1)+c*sp%y2(k)+d*sp%y2(k+1)

    RETURN
end function sp_interpolate_slope

elemental function sp_interpolate_slope2(sp,x) result(yp2)
! =====================================================
! Subroutine that does the actual interpolation
! Input arrays of x_in and y_in=f(x), spline_res is the result of
! the 'spline' subroutine, x is the corresponding value we are looking for
! i.e. (time_at_max in hubble), yp is the output result 2nd slope
! =====================================================
class(spline), intent(in) :: sp
real(wp), intent(in) :: x
real(wp) :: yp2
integer:: n, k 
real(wp):: a, b, c, d, h, t
    n = size(sp%y)
    k= sp%indexof(x)
    
    h = sp%x(k+1) - sp%x(k)
    IF (h == 0) error STOP "Bad x input"
    t = (x-sp%x(k))/h
    a = 0.0_wp
    b = 0.0_wp
    if( x>=sp%x(k) .and. x<=sp%x(k+1)) then
        ! Cubic inside the interval
        c = 1-t
        d = t
    else
        ! Linear outside the interval
        c = 0.0_wp
        d = 0.0_wp
    end if
    yp2 = a*sp%y(k)+b*sp%y(k+1)+c*sp%y2(k)+d*sp%y2(k+1)
    RETURN
end function sp_interpolate_slope2

pure function sp_find_local_extrema(sp, x_low, x_high) result(x)
class(spline), intent(in) :: sp
real(wp) :: x
real(wp), intent(in), optional :: x_low, x_high
integer :: n, k1, k2
real(wp) :: x1, x2, yp1, yp2, h, tol, yp
    n = size(sp%y)
    if(present(x_low)) then
        x1 = x_low
    else
        x1 = sp%x(1)
    end if
    if(present(x_high)) then
        x2 = x_high
    else
        x2 = sp%x(n)
    end if
    h = x2 - x1
    tol = h/(2**23)
    yp1 = sp_interpolate_slope(sp, x1)
    yp2 = sp_interpolate_slope(sp, x2)
    
    if( yp1*yp2 > 0 ) then
        ! no solution
        if( yp1>0 ) then
            x = big
        else
            x = tiny
        end if
    end if
    
    do while (x2-x1>tol)
        x = (x1+x2)/2
        yp = sp_interpolate_slope(sp, x)
        if( yp1*yp > 0) then
            x1 = x
            yp1 = yp
        else
            x2 = x
            yp2 = yp
        end if
    end do
    
end function

end module mod_splines
```

- GitHub repo for the code above: [FortranConsoleSpline](https://github.com/ja72/FortranConsoleSpline)

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I’m going to try to compile it in f2py3 and see if I get better results. (Ps. The plot is the same that I have, I just reversed the y-axis since brightest means least magnitude)

Comment: Hey John, this works perfectly to interpolate the time of maximum brightness, thanks. However I also need to interpolate the brightness 15 days after the maximum. How can i do this since I don't input in the call which point i want to interpolate?

Comment: if `x` holds the time of maximum brightness then, `y = sp%value(x+15.0_wp)` should return the brightness after 15 days. @MarcoLeonardi

Comment: Yeah i had figured it out. Thank you so much, this will improve my project a lot :)

Comment: @MarcoLeonardi - I hope it does not blow up on you later .. ha a little supernova joke there.